# Is there any risk to change www-data to root in Nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I have encountered a permission error serving my files so I changed the

`user www-data;`

to

`user root;`

in the nginx.conf file.

Is there any risk to do so?

Comment: Running a process as root to resolve permission errors is never a good idea.  Ever.

Comment: never run a public daemon as root or you can also write the root password on the website's index page and wrote on dont use it ;)

Comment: @djdomi Just wondering, is there any reference about this hacking? Thanks

Comment: it is a general knowledge that a process that runs under root can be easiest compromised. the only wqy may a unpriviledged container for a test environment but not for a productivity one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are risks and it is not recommended at all. Enabling the setting you mentioned would lead to Nginx not dropping any privileges upon running its worker processes.

You may want to read "[What are the security risks of running a daemon as root even though SELinux is enforcing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184299/what-are-the-security-risks-of-running-a-daemon-as-root-even-though-selinux-is-e)", which is partially related.

In the specific case of Nginx, over the last 11 years, there would have been the following vulnerabilities that would most likely have enabled someone to take over your whole machine:

- [CVE-2014-0088](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0088/)
- [CVE-2014-0133](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0133/)
- [CVE-2013-2028](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-2028/)
- [CVE-2012-2089](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-2089/)
- [CVE-2009-2629](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2009-2629/)